# Extending the branches of a tree with binary branches

Tags: trees, tikz-qtree

In the following tree, how can I introduce further and further binary branches between S and VP?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.S [.DP [.D the ] [.N pictures ] ] [.VP$’$  [.V display ] [.DP [.D the ] [.N man ] ]]]
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What is "S"? You mentioned  "between S and VP" but your tree has no "S" node.

Comment: I have changed the VP root to S.

Comment: Thanks. Still, it is not clear (at least to me) what you are trying to do. Can you describe your intent in more detail, please? Can you give us a drawing (even hand-drawn) of your desired tree?

Comment: Take the VP-V node with "display" on the V terminal node. How can I, say, replicate that VP-V node above its position indefinitely, so that we have many nodes of the same type above it?

Comment: Thanks for your effort trying to explain the desired output. However, I still don't quite understand the desiredt resulting tree. It would be of great help if you could add a little image of the tree that you want to build.

Comment: The problem is this. I'm trying to extend the branches of the tree in the rightward or leftward direction. I want all the branches to be binary so that the mother node of each branch directly dominates at most two nodes. However I do not know how to do it.

Comment: See for example, example (93) on page 28 of the following: http://www.sfu.ca/~kmoulton/Moulton_CPs.pdf                                                                         There are no three node trees (trees in which there is a constituent that dominates more than two nodes). I cannot extend a tree structure with this pattern. How do I do it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24876/discussion-between-gonzalo-medina-and-user65526).

Comment: It's still extremely clear to me. Where are there clear discussions of the rules governing the indentations in the tree you sent me?

Comment: @user65526 The documentation for `qtree` provides an algorithm for translating a tree into the square-brackets-and-dots syntax these packages use. I know you aren't using `qtree`, but perhaps that explanation would be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand where your confusion lies, since the (`tikz-`)`qtree` syntax for this is pretty standard in-line bracket structure (plus periods and spaces in the right places). You just use `[.` to introduce a node, which can be followed by further instances of `[.` to create recursion. Then use `<space>]` to close each node.

Here's a tree with some extra structure between VP and S.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree [.TP [.DP [.D the ] [.NP \edge[roof]; {pictures} ] ] [.T\1 [.T ] [.AspP [.Asp ] [.\emph{v}P [.\emph{v} ] [.VP [.V display ] [.DP [.D the ] [.NP \edge[roof]; {man} ] ] ] ] ] ] ]
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want, you can use indentation in your code to help you see the structure, but that has nothing to do with how the code is actually parsed by the program. The crucial thing is just to have some whitespace between nodes and closing brackets, whether a single space, multiple spaces, or a line break and tabs. This indented code produces exactly the same output as the code above.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\Tree
[.TP
    [.DP
        [.D the ]
        [.NP \edge[roof]; {pictures} ]
    ]
    [.T\1
        [.T ]
        [.AspP
            [.Asp ]
            [.\emph{v}P
                [.\emph{v} ]
                [.VP
                    [.V display ]
                    [.DP
                        [.D the ]
                        [.NP \edge[roof]; {man} ]
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```